# Change qty script

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, frontend

I use a script to change the qty in the product view page and in the shopping cart page but I have a problem. when I decrease the qty instead the latest value to be 0 is -1. How I can stop the decrease button to remain on the 0 value?

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
         /********************* Qty Holder **************************/
        $(document).on("click", ".qtyplus", function(e) {
            // Stop acting like a button
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get its current value
            var currentVal = parseInt($(this).parents('.qty-changer').find('input.input-text.qty').val());

            // If is not undefined
            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                // Increment
                $(this).parents('.qty-changer').find('input.input-text.qty').val(currentVal + 1);
                $(this).parents('.qty-changer').find('.update-cart-item').show();
            } else {
                // Otherwise put a 0 there
                $(this).parents('.qty-changer').find('input.input-text.qty').val(1);
            }
        });
        // This button will decrement the value till 0
        $(document).on("click", ".qtyminus", function(e) {
            // Stop acting like a button
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the field name
            fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
            // Get its current value
            var currentVal = parseInt($(this).parents('.qty-changer').find('input.input-text.qty').val());

            // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0

            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal >= 0) {
                // Decrement one
                $(this).parents('.qty-changer').find('input.input-text.qty').val(currentVal - 1);
                $(this).parents('.qty-changer').find('.update-cart-item').show();
            } else {
                // Otherwise put a 0 there
                $(this).parents('.qty-changer').find('input.input-text.qty').val(1);
            }
        }); 
        
        
        $(".qtyplus").unbind('click').click(function(){
            if($(this).parent().parent().children(".control").children("input.input-text.qty").is(':enabled')){
                $(this).parent().parent().children(".control").children("input.input-text.qty").val((+$(this).parent().parent().children(".control").children("input.input-text.qty").val() + 1) || 0);
                $(this).parent().parent().children(".control").children("input.input-text.qty").trigger('change');
                $(this).focus();
            }
        });
        $(".qtyminus").unbind('click').click(function(){
            if($(this).parent().parent().children(".control").children("input.input-text.qty").is(':enabled')){
                $(this).parent().parent().children(".control").children("input.input-text.qty").val(($(this).parent().parent().children(".control").children("input.input-text.qty").val() - 1 > 0) ? ($(this).parent().parent().children(".control").children("input.input-text.qty").val() - 1) : 0);
                $(this).parent().parent().children(".control").children("input.input-text.qty").trigger('change');
                $(this).focus();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Inc/Dec button on PDP.

```
            <div class="field qty">
                <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control control-qty-cart">
                    <input type="number"
                           name="qty"
                           id="qty"
                           maxlength="12"
                           value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                           echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                           title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                           echo __('Qty') ?>" class="qty-default input-text qty"
                           data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                    />

                    <div class="control-qty">
                        <span class="quantity-controls quantity-plus">+</span>
                        <span class="quantity-controls quantity-minus">-</span>

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            require([
                                'jquery'
                            ], function ($) {
                                $('.quantity-plus').click(function () {
                                    $('.qty-default').val(Number($('.qty-default').val()) + 1);
                                });

                                $('.quantity-minus').click(function () {
                                    var value = Number($('.qty-default').val()) - 1;
                                    if (value > 0) {
                                        $('.qty-default').val(value);
                                    }

                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, there on my store I have grouped products and this code is not work, you have any idea why??

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because of this code:

```
if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal >= 0) {
            // Decrement one
            $(this).parents('.qty-changer').find('input.input-text.qty').val(currentVal - 1);
            $(this).parents('.qty-changer').find('.update-cart-item').show();
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $(this).parents('.qty-changer').find('input.input-text.qty').val(1);
        }
```

So currentVal may = 0, and then you are subtracting 1 from it here:

```
.val(currentVal - 1)
```

If this is the case you need to alter your logic, maybe change `currentVal >= 0` to `currentVal > 0`?

Comment: thank you, if I change as you said: currentVal > 0 instead of -1 there is 1, I need to be 0

Comment: Add another else statement to handle currentVal being 0.

Comment: I recommend using Vrajesh's solution, yours is unnecessarily complex just to increment and decrement the quantity.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a small solution magento 2.4.3 for the cart page:**

Here it is so that the buttons -/+ per click updates the data. But additionally with the entry in the input field an update button appears which updates the quantity by clicking on it.

copy:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml
```

to your design folder:

```
app/design/{your_theme}/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml
```

Change line 97:

```
<td class="col qty" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>">
```

to:

```
<td class="col qty" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" data-id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>">
```

Change Line 99-115:

```
<div class="control qty">
    <label for="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty">
        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span>
        <input id="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty"
               name="cart[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>][qty]"
               data-cart-item-id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getSku()) ?>"
               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getQty()) ?>"
               type="number"
               size="4"
               step="any"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
               class="input-text qty"
               data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
               data-item-qty="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getQty()) ?>"
               data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="control qty" data-mage-init='{"Magento_Checkout/js/update_qty": {}}'>
    <label for="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty">
        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span>
        <a class="qty -minus">-</a>
        <input id="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty"
               name="cart[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>][qty]"
               data-cart-item-id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getSku()) ?>"
               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getQty()) ?>"
               type="number"
               size="4"
               step="any"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
               class="input-text qty"
               data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
               data-item-qty="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getQty()) ?>"
               data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
        <a class="qty -plus">+</a>
    </label>
    <a class="hidden update-btn cursor-pointer" id="update-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Update')) ?></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

add a new file to your design folder: app/design/{your_theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', 'a.qty', function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                productId = $(this).parents('td').data('id'),
                updateInput = $("#cart-" + productId + "-qty"),
                currentQty = updateInput.val();

            if ($this.hasClass('-plus')) {
                var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty) + parseInt(1);
                updateInput.val(newAdd);
                ajaxUpdate();
            } else if ($this.hasClass('-minus')) {
                if (currentQty > 1) {
                    var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty) - parseInt(1);
                    updateInput.val(newAdd);
                }
                ajaxUpdate();
            }

        });
        $(document).on('change', 'input.input-text.qty', function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                productId = $(this).parents('td').data('id'),
                updateButton = $("#update-" + productId + "-qty");

            updateButton.show().removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
            $(updateButton).on('click', function () {
                ajaxUpdate();
            });
        });

        function ajaxUpdate() {
            var form = $('form#form-validate.form-cart');
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: "POST",
                data: form.serialize(),
                showLoader: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res),
                        result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate.form-cart"),
                        sections = ['cart'];

                    form.replaceWith(result);

                    // The mini cart reloading
                    customerData.reload(sections, true);

                    // The totals summary block reloading
                    var deferred = $.Deferred();
                    getTotalsAction([], deferred);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    console.log(err.Message);
                }
            });
            return true;
        };
    });
});
```